# Check if another batch file is still running

Tags: windows, batch-file, process, cmd

I want `batch1.bat` to check if `batch2.bat` is running. If `batch2.bat` is running, I want nothing to happen. If `batch2.bat` is NOT running, I want `batch1.bat` to kill the process `process1.exe`.

In other words, I want `batch1.bat` to start `batch2.bat` and wait for it to be closed. Once it is closed, I want `process1.exe`to be ended.

How would I write `batch1.bat`?

Comment: You describe two different requirements: Checking if some other script is running and waiting for that other script to finish!

Comment: Hmm...well batch2.bat runs process1.exe, and if batch2.bat is closed (manually) before  process1.exe is, then things in process1.exe get messed up. I'm just trying to make sure process1.exe doesn't get messed up. So i want batch1.bat to kind of watch over the situation, and make sure if batch2.bat gets closed, process1.exe gets closed too. Kinda get what I am saying? I'm very new to this, so I'm not sure what the best path to take is to solve this.

Comment: I've included a sample skeleton. But, if batch2 can be closed, batch1 can also be closed. The "best" path seems to change the behaviour of process1

Comment: How do you run process1 from batch2? If it is launched with
**START /WAIT "process1.exe"**
then batch2 will never close itself until process1 terminates gracefully. 
However, if batches and processes can be broken by a malicious user, there's very little you can do about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch1.cmd

```
@echo off
  echo 1: starting
  echo 1: calling batch2

  cmd /c "batch2.cmd"

  echo 1: back to batch1
  echo 1: end batch1

  taskkill /im process1.exe /f >nul 2>nul
```

Batch2.cmd

```
@echo off
  echo 2: starting batch2
  echo 2: in batch2
  pause
  echo 2: leaving batch2
```