# Batch Script - Break out of loop when another batch has finished

Tags: windows, loops, batch-file, conditional-statements

I have a very simple script that merges all .txt files in a folder, as bellow:

```
copy /b *.txt Merged_output.txt >nul
```

This does the job and doesn't print anything and this is ok (I don't want it to print the name of every file it merges)

But I would like to see that script is still running until it ends merging all the .txt files.
I have a lot o files to merge (8000+) and this takes some time, and I have no idea if it still runs.

I was thinking of creating another batch script having a loop, that prints over and over again this message: Running...
Something as bellow:

```
@echo off
cls
:start
cls
echo Running...
goto start
```

I was wondering if it is possible to start from the Loop Script, printing the Running message and make it stop after it runs the merging.bat script and after the merging finishes.

Any other suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: It´s not a duplicate question? Did you see this?: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22165412/check-if-another-batch-file-is-still-running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need another batch file. Instead of hiding the output, mask it

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set monitor=cmd /q /v /e /c"for /l %%a in () do set/p.=&&echo !time! working || exit"

    copy /b *.txt merged_output | %monitor%
    echo %time% done
```

It just pipes the output of the `copy` command to a separate `cmd` instance that loops reading each line and printing the current time and the `working` literal.